# Register and Resolve DI containers in Prism 7 - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, prism-7

I'm using prism 7 for my new xamarin forms application.I have gone through [this](http://brianlagunas.com/whats-new-in-prism-for-xamarin-forms-7-0/) document.

I have couple of questions:

1. There are few DI interfaces I register after the app starts. We can use `IContainerRegistry` in app.xaml.cs to register but if we want to register or resolve in other pages, is there any way to get do it other that saving the `IContainerRegistry` and `IContainerRegistry` instance from app.xaml.cs and using it where ever we want?
2. To register a type the syntax is :

   `ContainerRegistry.RegisterInstance<ITextService>(new TextService());`

But how can we register a singleton?
I saw few examples but I did not really understand how to do it? can anyone please show an example?

**UPDATE:**

To register a singleton, 
The syntax seems like
`containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ILoggerFacade, EmptyLogger>();` but if we just pass the type without creating an instance ( in this case, the instance of EmptyLogger), how can we use properly register them?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `how can we use properly register them?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To register a type the syntax is: `ContainerRegistry.RegisterInstance<ITextService>(new TextService());`

this registers an instance not a type, btw, to register a type do `ContainerRegistry.Register<IAnInterface, SomeImplementation>();`

> But how can we register a singleton?

`ContainerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ITextService, TextService>();` does this, and btw, an instance is a singleton by nature (because the di container always has to inject the one instance you registered as it cannot create new instances on its own)

> is there any way to get do it other that saving the `IContainerRegistry` and `IContainerRegistry` instance from `app.xaml.cs` and using it where ever we want?

I recommend registering everything in one place rather than scattering registrations all over the project. But if you're determined, you can have `IContainerRegistry` injected anywhere and register your stuff.